# Add custom attributes to sorting options for sort and order WooCommerce products

Tags: woocommerce, attributes, product

I would like on my site to be able to order the products page (woocommerce)
as well as with the classic settings

- sort by popularity
- sort by average rating
- sort by newness
- sort by price: low to high
- sort by price: high to low

but also with an attribute present in all products

- sort by my custom attribute: low to high
- sort by my custom attribute: high to low

I found various posts about it and made several tests ... but I'm not a programmer ... I still haven't been able to solve the problem.

I found this article

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/custom-sorting-options-ascdesc/

explaining how to add

- sort by random

and it works correctly
but I didn't understand, starting from this code what you need to add / modify to replace random with my custom attribute.

My attribute name is "pa_kj"
Its value is alphanumeric

I thank everyone in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I found this code on the net

https://gist.github.com/bekarice/0df2b2d54d6ac8076f84

```
<?php
/**
 * Adds WooCommerce catalog sorting options using postmeta, such as custom fields
 * Tutorial: http://www.skyverge.com/blog/sort-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/
**/
function skyverge_add_postmeta_ordering_args( $sort_args ) {
        
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    switch( $orderby_value ) {
    
        // Name your sortby key whatever you'd like; must correspond to the $sortby in the next function
        case 'location':
            $sort_args['orderby']  = 'meta_value';
            // Sort by meta_value because we're using alphabetic sorting
            $sort_args['order']    = 'asc';
            $sort_args['meta_key'] = 'location';
            // use the meta key you've set for your custom field, i.e., something like "location" or "_wholesale_price"
            break;
                
        case 'points_awarded':
            $sort_args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
            // We use meta_value_num here because points are a number and we want to sort in numerical order
            $sort_args['order'] = 'desc';
            $sort_args['meta_key'] = 'points';
            break;
        
    }
    
    return $sort_args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'skyverge_add_postmeta_ordering_args' );


// Add these new sorting arguments to the sortby options on the frontend
function skyverge_add_new_postmeta_orderby( $sortby ) {
    
    // Adjust the text as desired
    $sortby['location'] = __( 'Sort by location', 'woocommerce' );
    $sortby['points_awarded'] = __( 'Sort by points for purchase', 'woocommerce' );
    
    return $sortby;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'skyverge_add_new_postmeta_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'skyverge_add_new_postmeta_orderby' );
```

but it doesn't work with the latest version of Woocommerce, it always returns the page with no products found.

Is there anyone experienced who can recommend the code to be modified?

Thanks again

Comment: Same issue. Did you manage to solve this?